# How to extend an Android button and use an xml layout file

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to extend the android button class and have it use an xml layout file.

The reason I want to use an xml layout file is that my button needs to use a style and as far as I know, there isn't a way to set style programatically.

> public class BuyButton extends Button { ... }

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Button 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    style="@style/customButton"
/>
```

so that I can call:

```
new BuyButton(activity);
```

and have it create a button that has the style applied to it.

(I'm also open to other ways of getting the same result)

Answer (score 15):

Create a class that extends `Button`.

```
public class BuyButton extends Button {

    public BuyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

In your XML reference that custom class directly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<your.package.name.BuyButton 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
style="@style/customButton"/>
```

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error. it's complaing about the xml.


04-20 16:30:19.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18583): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class client.views.buttons.BuyButtonView

Answer (score 1):

In your layout .xml a one line change to the control type (change from Button to your custom button type ) will solve your casting problem.

For your subclassed BuyButton, find the button's section in .xml; it may look something like this:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
            android:layout_width="188dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Buy" />
```

and change it to this :

```
<yourpackage.name.BuyButton
            android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
            android:layout_width="188dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Buy" />
```

Comment: also - must have a constructor in your subclass that will allow inflation; you may also create other constructors that have different signatures, but the basic constructor taking parameters of context and attributes must be defined in your subclass. see : https://sholtz9421.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/correct-way-to-subclass-android-views/

Answer (score -1):

See the [Button Style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) section. Just set a custom background drawable.

Comment: I CANNOT do a custom background drawable. It must be a style.